# Outlook Interop Folder.CopyTo method work offline without server connection

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, com-interop, comobject

I'm trying to copy outlook inbox mail to new pst file with outlook interop. I can do with folder.CopyTo(destination) method and it works i can copy from ost to pst. But the problem is currenlty exchange server is not available and when i run the command without internet connection (or exchange server is unavailable to client ) i get exception saying "network problems are preventing connection to microsoft exchange."

If i try to read each item in outlook (.ost) one by one  and create copy of item and move it to new pst i can do it offline. But it's slower and mostly outlook is gets into not responding state.

Is it possbile to use  folder.CopyTo() method in outlook interop offline without server connection ?

Answer (score 0):

Open Outlook in cached mode, and then copy the Inbox folder to the target folder. There is a chance that not all content of the folder is cached on the client side, so it is not possible to copy the full content available on the server side only without a connection available.

Also you may check out the `DisableCrossAccountCopy` value in the window registry:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook
```

where 16.0 stands for the Outlook version. It has the side effect of disabling this method.

Comment: Thank you. Actually my test outlook profile is enabled for caching. It's strange that i can copy message and move it to different folder but not with folder.copyto() 
Do you think this "DisableCrossAccountCopy " doesn't allow me to copy from one folder to other one ? I will try now and update comment.

Comment: The cache period varies depending on your settings.

Comment: yes its about 1 year. I don't need more than 1 year. ı just need to copy existing data.But somehow requires echange server connection (only with copyto() ) method

Comment: Does the folder contains items older than one year?

Comment: yes i think it has

Comment: Well, try to create a folder and place there few email without old ones. Does it work in that case?